# Storing varied object types with order in Java

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to model a solar system in Java, and need to store different random amounts of objects types and preserve their order somehow. I am currently using the following class structure:

```
class PlanetarySystem - currently has a list of each object type (below)

class planetaryBody
         class star extends planetaryBody
         class planet extends planetaryBody
         class belt extends planetaryBody
         class disk extends planetaryBody
```

For example, lets say I want to loop through the system show the details of the PlaneitaryBody objects.  The stats for the Star would probably be different than a Planet, and so on.   Here is a simple example.

```
public class PlanetaryBody
{
     private String name;

     public PlanetaryBody()
     {
          this.name = "Generic Name";
     }

     public String getName()
     {
          return this.name;
     }
}

public class Star extends PlanetaryBody
{
     private int temperature;

     public Star()
     {
          this.temperature = 12345;
     }
     public String getTemp()
     {
          return this.getTemp();
     }

}
```

Now if I later create something like

```
List<planetaryBody> system = new List<planetaryBody>();
//then put some stars, planets, disks, etc in.
system.get(x).getName() //will work
system.get(x).getTemp() //will not work because type is planetaryBody
```

later I want to loop through the list and get lets say the name of everything, the temperature of the star, the size of the belt, the color of the planet, etc.  I don't think I will be able to pull out specific function for the subclasses.  That's the problem I am trying to solve.

Can I create something that allows me to store the objects in order, retain what they are, and then do something specific to that class later?

I was thinking of trying to use a map tree, but I think I would have to use it with the planetaryBody type.  That creates problems later when I am trying to pull the objects out later and they come out as planetaryBodies.  I've read that doing if statements to figure out what class they are isn't the best OOP practice, and honestly I don't even know if that would work as intended.

I'm new and learning, so examples, and further reading is appreciated.

edit: more clarification.

Comment: Just have a list of `PlanetaryBody` in `PlanetarySystem`. This list will be filled with instances of `Star`, `Planet`, `Belt` and on. Each of these classes should know how to display or how to behave independently.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need the Visitor pattern

Comment: @luiggiMendoza, that would mean i need to do something like List<PlanetaryBody>.  Which if I later use foo.get(bar) it would return an object type PlanetaryBody, and not Star or whatever.

Comment: @the1gofer and how do you know whether calling `foo.get(bar)` returns a `Star` or a `Planet`?

Comment: `somePlanet instanceof star` is true if `somePlanet` is of type `star`

Comment: @the1gofer that's the idea. If you're creating a parent class, that class should define the public behavior of the object, independent if it's a `Planet` or a `Star`. If you need to fire specific behavior on each item based on the `PlanetarySystem` object, then you need to implement observer/subscribe methods. I think you need to explain more which kind of problems you have. The more specific you are, the more accurate answer you'll get.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak.  wouldn't List<PlanetaryBody> system = new List< PlanetaryBody>() cast everything as a planetary bod?  so system.get(foo)  will always be returned as a PlanetaryBody object.  So if I need to do something star specific, for example, I won't be able to.    Maybe I am misunderstanding how that works.

Comment: I am thinking a list of stars, each star holding a list of planets, a planet optionally holding a disk, etc. That would give you the strong typing that would make `if (currentPlanetaryObject instanceof Planet)` superfluous. That said, there are different opinions on whether such `if` statements are bad.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak  I updated the question.  I'll research observer/subscribe methods.  I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: Well then, override the `getName()` method in `Star` class and there you will return a `String` containing its name and maybe more data like temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to your problem, each with their pros and cons, and also many opinions. I just wanted to present an old trick, here combined with a modern `Optional`. Superclass:

```
public abstract class PlanetaryBody {

    /**
     * @return If this PlanetaryBody is a Star, then an Optional containing this as a Star.
     * Otherwise an empty Optional.
     */
    public Optional<Star> asStar() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public Optional<Planet> asPlanet() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    // Similar methods for other subclasses

}
```

Example subclass:

```
public class Star extends PlanetaryBody {

    public void shineBrightly() {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Star> asStar() {
        return Optional.of(this);
    }

}
```

The above allows us to use the classes like this:

```
    PlanetaryBody body = // ...

    body.asStar().ifPresent(s -> {
        // body is a star
        s.shineBrightly();
    });
```

Pros:

- Flexible in that you can handle planetary bodies uniformly where appropriate and easily convert to concrete type where needed.
- Doesn’t use `instanceof` or other frowned-upon constructs.
- Type safe.

Cons:

- The classes are tightly coupled. The superclass needs to know its subclasses. You need to modify the superclass every time you add a subclass.
- It may be considered a bit wordy, and you need to get very similar code right in all subclasses.

**Edit:** I am using the `Optional` class introduced in Java 8. The main (only?) purpose is null-safe return values from methods. When a method may return something or nothing — as `asStar` may, for example — the old way would be to have it return a reference that could potentially be `null`. And this gave rise to `NullPointerException`s  when the caller wasn’t aware that the return value could be `null` or just forgot to check. Happened very often. You may argue that in this case it’s not a great risk, so we could live with returning either `this` as a `Star` or `null`.

With `Optional` the method needs never (and must never) return `null`. Instead it returns an `Optional` that either has a value in it or not. The way I usually use an `Optional` I get from a method is through its `isPresent` method as shown above. I pass a lambda (or method reference) to it, and the code inside is only executed if a value was present. So in my code `s` is a reference to the `Star` inside the `Optional` and is guaranteed to be non-null (otherwise the code wouldn’t be executed at all).

Java 9 introduced the variant `ifPresentOrElse` that will also execute a code block in the case where the `Optional` is empty.

You can of course read much more about `Optional` on the Internet. I’ve become quite fond of it. I recommend the slide deck in the link below if you can read it out of context of the talk — otherwise the talk is also available on YouTube. One word of caution: If you read somewhere that you should use the methods `Optional.isPresent` and `Optional.get`, don’t believe that, you very rarely should (note the difference between `isPresent` with s and `ifPresent` with f, both methods exist, use the latter as I do).

**Variant that doesn’t use `Optional`** (not tested). In the superclass:

```
    public Star asStar() {
        return null;
    }
```

In the concrete subclass:

```
    public Star asStar() {
        return this;
    }
```

How to use:

```
    if (body.asStar() != null) {
        // body is a star
        body.asStar().shineBrightly();
    }
```

**Link:**  [Slide deck *Optional: The Mother of All Bikesheds* by Stuart Marks, Oracle](https://stuartmarks.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/optionalmotherofallbikesheds3.pdf)

Comment: This is good... can you provide a little clarification on the
     body.asStar().ifPresent(s -> { ... }  portion?

It looks like its getting a star object from asStar() then if it's not empty, assigning that to the name s?   

I just haven't run into this  syntax before.